# Implement react-router PrivateRoute in Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-router

Here is an example from react-router for how to add a component for protected routes:

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

I have tried to implement this functionality in my Typescript project, using the example above as inspiration.

**components/Routes**

```
import PrivateRoute from '../../connectors/PrivateRoute';
<PrivateRoute path="/codes" component={SomePage} />
```

**connectors/PrivateRoute**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { AppState } from 'app-types';
import PrivateRouteComponent from '../../components/PrivateRoute';

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
    const isSignedIn = state.user.isSignedIn;

    return {
        isSignedIn
    };
};

const PrivateRoute = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null
)(PrivateRouteComponent);

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**components/PrivateRoute**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    Route,
    Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';

interface PrivateRouteProps {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    component: any;
    isSignedIn: boolean;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    location: any;
}

const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
    const { component: Component, isSignedIn, location, ...rest } = props;

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(routeProps) =>
                isSignedIn ? (
                    <Component {...routeProps} />
                ) : (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: '/signin',
                                state: { from: location }
                            }}
                        />
                    )
            }
        />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**Error**

```
(105,18): Type '{ path: string; component: ConnectedComponentClass<typeof SomePage, Pick<SomePageProps, never>>; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Pick<PrivateRouteProps, "location" | "component">>'.
  Property 'location' is missing in type '{ path: string; component: ConnectedComponentClass<typeof SomePage, Pick<SomePageProps, never>>; }'.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error occurs because `PrivateRouteProps` has a required property `location` that isn't provided when you use `PrivateRoute` in `components/Routes.tsx`.  I assume that this location should instead come from the `routeProps` that the router automatically passes to the `render` function of the route, as it did in the original example.  Once this is fixed, another error is exposed: `components/Routes.tsx` is passing a `paths` property that isn't declared in `PrivateRouteProps`.  Since `PrivateRoute` is passing any prop it doesn't know about to `Route`, `PrivateRouteProps` should extend `RouteProps` from `react-router` so that `PrivateRoute` accepts all props accepted by `Route`.

Here is `components/PrivateRoute.tsx` after both fixes:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    Route,
    Redirect,
    RouteProps,
} from 'react-router-dom';

interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    component: any;
    isSignedIn: boolean;
}

const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
    const { component: Component, isSignedIn, ...rest } = props;

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(routeProps) =>
                isSignedIn ? (
                    <Component {...routeProps} />
                ) : (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: '/signin',
                                state: { from: routeProps.location }
                            }}
                        />
                    )
            }
        />
    );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: That is just awsome! If I may ask a follow-up question: how come I need to extent PrivateRouteProps with RouteProps, when I generally don't need to do that in my other components?

Comment: The purpose of extending `RouteProps` in this case is to accept the `path` prop so it can be passed on to `Route`.  If the other components you are talking about wrap `Route` and pass along props in the same way that `PrivateRoute` does, I expect their prop types would need to extend `RouteProps`; if those components don't wrap `Route`, then `RouteProps` is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53111155/65555) very useful but needed it to work for `children` as well as `component`, so tweaked as follows:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fakeAuth } from '../api/Auth';

interface PrivateRouteProps extends RouteProps {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  component?: any;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  children?: any;
}

const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
  const { component: Component, children, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={routeProps =>
        fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
          Component ? (
            <Component {...routeProps} />
          ) : (
            children
          )
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/signin',
              state: { from: routeProps.location },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Note: This happens to be using `fakeAuth` like the original [training article](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) rather than user1283776's `isSignedIn` redux stuff, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The current answers work but I would like to post my solution as I think it has a few advantages:

- Not overriding the property `component` with the type `any`.
- Leveraging the [render method from the library](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/ea44618e68f6a112e48404b2ea0da3e207daf4f0/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L54) to support both - `<Route>` Component and children props - without reimplementing already present framework logic/code.
- Using [`Recipe: Static Typing`](http://%20https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically) from the official `react-redux` documentation

Example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';
import {
    Redirect,
    Route,
    RouteProps,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppState } from '../store';

const mapState = (state: AppState) => ({
  loggedIn: state.system.loggedIn,
});

const connector = connect(
  mapState,
  { }
);

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

type Props = PropsFromRedux & RouteProps & {

};

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    const { loggedIn, ...rest } = props;

    return ( !loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/login/" /> :
      <Route {...rest} />
    );
};

export default connector(PrivateRoute);
```